# Getting Time difference in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 2 time fields like `hh:mm` and I need to get the difference.

Example: The difference between 11:55 and 11:25 should be .30 or 30.
How can I achieve this?

It was in AM/PM format like 11:55 AM AND 11:25 AM. I have changed to normal time time using `from_unixtime` function but now unable to get difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select (unix_timestamp(end_time, 'HH:mm') 
- unix_timestamp(start_time, 'HH:mm'))/60 from  temp.test_table;
```

You should convert both dates to seconds and then substract them. Finally, if you want the result in minutes, divide it by 60.

Code Example:

```
create  table temp.test_table (                                                                                                                                                                                     
        start_time                  CHAR(5) 
        ,end_time                  CHAR(5) 
)
stored as parquet location '../temp.db/test_table';
```

```
INSERT INTO TABLE temp.test_table VALUES ('11:25', '11:55');
```

```
select (unix_timestamp(end_time, 'HH:mm') 
- unix_timestamp(start_time, 'HH:mm'))/60 from  temp.test_table;
```

Result:  30.0